How to make a Daytime Convection RGB from Himawari-9 NetCDF
I'm trying to make an RGB image from Himawari-9 NetCDF using the Daytime Convection Recipe through Python centered in one part of the Philippines. I have downloaded the individual near-IR and IR bands from the NCEI's THREDDS (particularly B03, B05, B07, B08, B10, and B13). Unfortunately, when I tried to visualize it with cartopy and matplotlib, it only produces the (headscratching) image below.

The MWE is as follows.
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

data_dir = Path("Daytime RGB")

B03 = xr.open_dataset(data_dir / 'H8_B03_0700.nc')
B05 = xr.open_dataset(data_dir / 'H8_B05_0700.nc')
B07 = xr.open_dataset(data_dir / 'H8_B07_0700.nc')
B08 = xr.open_dataset(data_dir / 'H8_B08_0700.nc')
B10 = xr.open_dataset(data_dir / 'H8_B10_0700.nc')
B13 = xr.open_dataset(data_dir / 'H8_B13_0700.nc')

dx1 = B03.isel(time=0, x=slice(5900, 9000, 1), y=slice(5900, 9000, 1))
dx2 = B05.isel(time=0, x=slice(1500, 1975, 1), y=slice(1700, 2050, 1))
dx3 = B07.isel(time=0, x=slice(1500, 1975, 1), y=slice(1700, 2050, 1))
dx4 = B08.isel(time=0, x=slice(1500, 1975, 1), y=slice(1700, 2050, 1))
dx5 = B10.isel(time=0, x=slice(1500, 1975, 1), y=slice(1700, 2050, 1))
dx6 = B13.isel(time=0, x=slice(1500, 1975, 1), y=slice(1700, 2050, 1))

dx = xr.merge([dx1.interp_like(dx2), dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5, dx6]) #dx1 interp to 2 km

central_longitude = dx1['geostationary'].longitude_of_projection_origin
satellite_height = dx1['geostationary'].satellite_height

red1 = dx['channel_0010_brightness_temperature'].to_numpy()
red2 = dx['channel_0008_brightness_temperature'].to_numpy()

blue1 = dx['channel_0013_brightness_temperature'].to_numpy()
blue2 = dx['channel_0007_brightness_temperature'].to_numpy()

green1 = dx['channel_0003_scaled_radiance'].to_numpy()
green2 = dx['channel_0005_scaled_radiance'].to_numpy()

r = np.diff(red1 - red2)
g = np.diff(blue1 - blue2)
b = np.diff(green1 - green2)

# Extract the coordinate variables
mapx = dx['x'].to_numpy()
mapy = dx['y'].to_numpy()

rgb = np.stack((r, g, b), axis=-1) #I think I missed something here, like the gamma or some clipping?

data_proj = ccrs.Geostationary(
    central_longitude=central_longitude, 
    satellite_height=satellite_height,
)
map_proj = ccrs.Miller(central_longitude=central_longitude)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(20, 12), dpi=300,
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj),
)

pcm = ax.pcolorfast(mapx, mapy, rgb, transform=data_proj)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('10m'), linewidth=1.5, color='b')
ax.set_extent([118.0, 126.0, 13.0, 18.9]) # Luzon

plt.savefig('test.jpg', dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show

For testing, the individual bands are included here. Although, I'm not completely comfortable/advanced in with Python. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Running your code produces the following warning:
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data 
([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers). Got range [-24.9375..36.8125].

So rescale your data 0-1:
r = (r - r.min()) / (r.max() - r.min())
g = (g - g.min()) / (g.max() - g.min())
b = (b - b.min()) / (b.max() - b.min())

Also, a couple of other things to note:

You don't need to use np.diff, just calculate the difference by subtracting; and
You haven't applied the gamma correction noted in the PDF you linked to (red γ=1.0, green γ=0.5 and blue γ=0.95).

So the final code might look like:
# Calc difference
r = (red1 - red2)
g = (blue1 - blue2)
b = (green1 - green2)

# Rescale 0-1 and apply gamma
r = (r - r.min()) / (r.max() - r.min())  # gamma is 1 so ignore
g = ((g - g.min()) / (g.max() - g.min())) ** (1/0.5)
b = ((b - b.min()) / (b.max() - b.min())) ** (1/0.95)


